# Передача значения переменной из bat файла или хидера в переменную qMake

Tags: qt, bat, qmake, version

Я хочу добавить к имени исполняемого файла, генерируемого в Qt Creator 4.9.1 на Win 11, номер сборки VAR:
TARGET = My_proj_$${VAR}

Чтобы получить значение VAR я использовал решение из этого ответа:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17443713

В итоге, сделав все как в сообщении по ссылке, у меня в хидере есть определение BUILD c правильным номером сборки и есть echo от выполнения bat файла с таким же правильным номером сборки.

Как взять значение номера сборки от одного из этих 2х источников и передать в переменную VAR?

Comment: `VAR=$$system(get_echo.bat)` работает ? Что в переменной VAR?

Comment: Вместо:
build_nr.commands = $$PWD/build_inc.bat  
build_nr.depends = FORCE                 
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += build_nr          
PRE_TARGETDEPS += build_nr
..................
Сделал:
VAR=$$system(build_inc.bat)
...................
В итоге исполняемый файл не запускается, пишет "Не удалось запустить программу. Путь или права недопустимы?", но пишет что пробует запустить my_proj_19, а директории сборки создает файл my_proj_16
..................
В VAR ничего нет, я не знаю как в нее поместить значение нужной мне переменной.

Comment: Причем теперь инкремент номера сборки происходит в файле, который лежит в директории, где находятся файлы проекта и build.h создается теперь там же. Так даже лучше- решается проблема с учетом файлов номера сборки в гите, потому что директорию теневой сборки я некомичу, а раньше все файлы были там.